# matlab align to center a text of excel cell

Tags: excel, matlab, text-alignment

I have a question: how can I put the values of 'values{num_rows+1}' in the center of the excel cell?
I saw that I have to use the function: set(ActivesheetRange,'HorizontalAlignment',3); but I don't know how to use it.

```
e = actxserver ('Excel.Application'); %# open Activex server
filename = fullfile(pwd,'example2.xlsx'); %# full path required
ewb = e.Workbooks.Open(filename); %# open the file
esh = ewb.ActiveSheet;


str = num2str(num_rows+1);
esh.Range(strcat('J',str)).Interior.Color = clr;

sheet1=e.Worksheets.get('Item', 'Sheet1');
range1=get(sheet1,'Range', strcat('A',str),strcat('I',str));
range1.Value= set(values{num_rows+1},'HorizontalAlignment',,'center');
```

thank everyone :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Excel VBA object model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814737.aspx), not MATLAB text properties.

To align cell value to center:

```
range1.HorizontalAlignment = -4108;
```

In this statement `-4108` is `xlCenter` constant defined in the Excel object model. Don't know how to access it from MATLAB by its name.